# Get count of users while reading from AAD [Microsoft Graph]

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I was following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp to run some graph query on AAD objects as follows:

```
await _graphServiceClient
         .Users.Request()
         .Request(new Option[] { new QueryOption("$count", "true") })
         .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
         .Filter("endsWith(mail,'tenant.com')")
         .GetAsync();
```

I see the following error:

[image]

What am I missing and how do I resolve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await _graphServiceClient
         .Users.Request(new Option[] { new QueryOption("$count", "true") })
         .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
         .Filter("endsWith(mail,'tenant.com')")
         .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

To retrieve the list of users with **`Mail-ID`**, I executed the below query in [**Microsoft Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(mail,'@tenant.com')

ConsistencyLevel:eventual
```

**Response:**

[image]

**You can make use of the below sample CSharp code:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};
var users = await graphClient.Users
.Request( queryOptions )
.Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
.Filter("endsWith(mail,'@tenant.com')")
.GetAsync();
```